# row_number error when trying to rank items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get back into SQL queries and am having a frustrating problem.

I'm trying to take all items in my dataset and rank them by partitions. I researched this and think it should look like this:

```
select g.ticker, g.sector, g.industry, g.countryname, g.exchange, c.carbon, c.year,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY g.sector, g.industry, g.countryname, g.exchange
    ORDER BY c.carbon DESC
    ) AS 'Rank'
from "General" g 
INNER JOIN carbon c ON upper(c.ticker) =g.ticker ;
```

The output would be a rank for each group in the partition in this case it would be sector, industry, country name and exchange then the rows are ranked based on their carbon emissions.

I'm getting this error:

```
Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'Rank'"
  Position: 1305
```

if I remove the rank section, the data joins and provides results (obviously not ranked like I want but I know the base query works). What am I doing wrong?

Second (related) question, I forgot how much I hated SQL error messages. The above error tells me there's a syntax error then I went to the docs and couldn't see anything different in my code vs their example.  Assuming lack of experience, is there a better way to get actionable error messages (i.e. in Python I get a stack trace that I can read to see what part of my code went wrong)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Also, I would suggest avoiding anything that is part of standard SQL (which has a `rank()` function.  I often use `seqnum`:

```
select g.ticker, g.sector, g.industry, g.countryname, g.exchange, c.carbon, c.year,
       row_number() over (
           partition by g.sector, g.industry, g.countryname, g.exchange
           order by c.carbon desc
                         ) as seqnum
from "General" g join
     carbon c 
     on upper(c.ticker) = g.ticker ;
```

Note:   You should only use single quotes for string and date constants.  If you want to escape a column name, use double quotes (just as your query does for the table name `General`).

Comment: oh my god! I changed Rank to seqnum and it worked. I was losing my mind(and maybe some hairs over the quotes and variable name! I thought it was a larger problem. Thank you so much Gordon. In the past few days you have helped me a lot and incread my confidence. 

Short of being smarter, is there a way I could have troubleshooter better? I find the error messages aren't helpful to beginners.

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . It is not a matter of intelligence, just practice.  Two recommendations to avoid this type of error:  don't escape identifiers and avoid naming anything after words you "recognize" in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I think first step in this journey is to learn SQL words :-) I've gotten in trouble with escapes. I'm going to force myself to use single unless proven otherwise. I'm used to python where allows me to use both.